# how to write a rounding constraint for optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

I have an optimization problem as follows:

minimize    $\sum_i \sum_j x_i x_j S_{ij}$

subject to the constraints:

$\sum_i  x_i = 1 $

and

$x_i$  are rounded  in  increments  of 0.01.

question is if there is a way I can implement the rounding constraint while still being within a continuous framework(i.e. using a computation library which can perform the computation with continuous $x_i$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. Possible values are 0, 0.01, 0.02, which are inherently discrete. You can replace $x_i$ by $z_i/100$ where $z_i$ is an integer value, but that's about it. (This isn't homework, by any chance?)

Comment: However, you can solve the continuous problem (all local extrema), then expect the solution(s) to have the $x_i$ within rounding distance of the continuous solution. This gives you only a few possibles to check. Note that you need to check all local extrema, not just the global extrema,